# Node.js Mongodb Crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an express.js app , i am using mongodb for database and Mongoose driver.

Also using elasticsearch for searching.

After running my app after couple hours mongodb crash and i have to restart MongoD.

The Problem is dont show any error and i dont how find problem.

Only thing i know in something related to mongodb query

here is the error i get :

```
Error
    at Error.MongoError (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:13:17)
    at Function.MongoError.create (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:29:11)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:140:22)
    at Socket.g (events.js:180:16)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at TCP.close (net.js:466:12)
```

here is one of my routes :

```
router.get('/artist/:id/:path', function(req, res, next) {

    var pageNumber = req.params.page; 
    var skip = pageNumber * 50;
    var path = req.params.path;
    var singerID = parseInt(req.params.id);

    singer.findOne({"singerId":singerID}).exec(function(err, items) {
    if(err) throw err;
    var ArtistName = items.artist_name
    Keyword.find( { $text: { $search: items.artist_name } } ).count().exec(function(err, count) {



            Keyword.find( { $text: { $search: items.artist_name } } ).skip(skip).limit(50).lean().exec(function(err, items) {

            var total = Math.ceil(count/50);
                // random keyword
                Keyword.count({}, function (err, count) {
                    if (err) {
                        return next(err);
                    }
                    var skip = Math.floor((Math.random() * count) + 1);
                    Keyword.find().skip(skip).limit(100).lean().exec(function(err, keywords) {
                            if (err) {
                                return next(err);
                            }
                    // res.send
                        res.render('singerPage',{singer: items, pageNumber:0,count:total,id:singerID,path:path,artistName:ArtistName,keywords:keywords});
                    });
                }) // end random keyword

            });
    })
 })

})
```

### update

here is the last mongodb log :

```
2015-08-13T06:53:08.285+0000 I QUERY    [conn17] query music.keywords planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:35095187651 ntoreturn:100 ntoskip:444502 nscanned:0 nscannedObjects:444602 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:3474 nreturned:100 reslen:19070 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 6950 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 3475 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 3475 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 3475 } } } 113ms
2015-08-13T06:53:12.430+0000 I QUERY    [conn18] query music.keywords planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:35263643264 ntoreturn:100 ntoskip:395246 nscanned:0 nscannedObjects:395346 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:3088 nreturned:100 reslen:14874 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 6178 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 3089 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 3089 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 3089 } } } 103ms
2015-08-13T06:53:23.580+0000 I QUERY    [conn18] killcursors  keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 1 } } } 13ms
2015-08-13T06:53:27.776+0000 I QUERY    [conn16] query music.keywords planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:35959352048 ntoreturn:100 ntoskip:407328 nscanned:0 nscannedObjects:407428 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:3183 nreturned:100 reslen:17946 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 6368 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 3184 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 3184 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 3184 } } } 107ms
```

Comment: have you checked mongodb log ?

Comment: @Hiren updated question.

Comment: Edit /etc/mongodb.conf and turn verbose logging on.  Uncomment:
    #verbose = true;  Then restart mongodb service, sudo service mongodb restart;  That might show more information.

Comment: @ErickGriffin  i wants know there is any chance mongoose have problem with mongodb 3 ?

Comment: Yes, its possible did you check their bugzilla or other bug reporting repos?